# Deployment via tomcat7-maven-plugin keeps adding "/deploy?path" to the target path

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7, catalina

I'm trying to deploy a new version of my app to the path `/app-test` using the `##` notation.

I've set the `warFileName` in `pom.xml` to be `app-test##2021-01-21-pkix-fix` and then called

```
mvn clean tomcat7:deploy
```

which generates and builds a `.war` successfully:

```
...
[INFO] Generating war /xyz/target/app-test##2021-01-21-pkix-fix.war
[INFO] Building war: /xyz/target/app-test##2021-01-21-pkix-fix.war
```

As it proceeds to upload the resources, it tries to do so multiple times **while adding `/deploy?path` for the 2nd time**. The third attempt makes even less sense:

```
[INFO] Deploying war to http://mydomain.eu/app-test##2021-01-21-pkix-fix
  
Uploading: http://mydomain.eu/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix
Uploaded: http://mydomain.eu/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix 

Uploading: https://mydomain.eu/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix
Uploaded: https://mydomain.eu/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix

Uploading: https://mydomain.eu/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix
Uploaded: https://mydomain.eu/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix/deploy?path=%2Fapp-test%23%232021-01-21-pkix-fix
```

The deployment then fails:

```
FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /app-test##2021-01-21-pkix-fix/deploy?path=/app-test##2021-01-21-pkix-fix
```

because **paths must not contain the `=` char** which is confirmed by the `catalina-daemon.out` error log:

```
...
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character '=' in value part of property
    at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:618)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(ObjectName.java:1382)
...
```

Here's my condensed [`pom.xml`](https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/d4ed92827a25c4159f96d59953cdb6f7).

I suspect this has to do with my relatively recent `mvn` upgrade through homebrew. Here's my current version:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Why does tomcat keep adding `/deploy?path` to my deployments?

---

As I'm investigating further, it's likely it's related to the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` but [the docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_a_Directory_or_WAR_by_URL) haven't really clarified anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all else fails, there's always the option to deploy the `.war` manually.

Package the program first:

```
mvn clean package [-P profile_name]
```

and then locate the `.war` in `/target`:

[image]